# Azure Pipelines – Release Gradle Pipeline is unable to find gradlew

Tags: android, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have successfully setup a pipleine such that when there's a PR to `dev` it runs a gradle task to run `gradlew testDebugUnitTests`. That works perfectly fine and as expected.

Here's the YAML

```yaml
trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'testDebugUnitTest'
```

Now I want to do an exact pipeline like that one but as a release pipeline, it should just run a different gradle task. I followed the UI (I can't edit the YAML output) and here's what it produces:

```yaml
steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: 'gradlew tpaDeployDebug'
  inputs:
    tasks: tpaDeployDebug
    publishJUnitResults: false
```

When the release pipeline triggers it fails stating that:
[image: Pipeline fail]

Here's how I setup the agent that runs the task:

[image: Agent screenshot]

I really don't know what went wrong (well of course it can't find the gradlew script file) or how to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your issue:

[image]

The reason for this error is that the path of the Gradle Wrapper is incorrect. Please follow the steps below to check whether there is anything missed.

1.Add your repository, or any other artifact that contains Gradle as your release pipeline's artifact. Here is an example of how to add a repository:

[image][image]

PS. Notice the value of `Source alias`, which will be used in the next step.

2.Set the value of Gradle wrapper to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Source alias)/gradlew`. You can also click the "Browse Graddle wrapper" button and select `gradle`.

[image]

3.Create a new release to see whether the issue is resolved.

Comment: I'll try this and I'll let you know. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Some random IT boy Hello, didn't get your latest information. Is there any updates for this issue? Please feel free to let me know whether my answer helps.

Comment: Company changed focus and they put me to develop an Angular application. I didn't get to try it :(

Maybe I can get some extra hours and try your answer out